# Vlookup next largest value

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I have some values that I am trying to use vlookup on, the values increment by 4, i.e. (14,18,22,...) I am trying to use vlookup on these values. The problem is that the search key values increment by one, so if the search value is for example 15, it will not be found.

Is there a way to vlookup the next largest value?

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
=iferror(vlookup(A1,E:E,1,0),indirect("E"&match(A1,E:E)+1))
```

where A1 is the cell for the search term and E:E is a list sorted ascending of values.

This should not require the steps to be `4` or uniform, but for values outside the quoted range you may wish to insert `0` (assuming only positive numbers are involved) at the top of the list and a very large number at the bottom.

The `vlookup` part looks for the value in the range E:E in the first column (there is only one for that range) and requires an exact match (`0`). Where there is no exact match this will return an error that is caught by `iferror` that instead applies the alternative part of the formula. This looks for an inexact match (E:E is assumed to be sorted ascending) so the inexact `match` will find the row number of the next lower value. Requirement is for next higher, so add one row and then apply `indirect` to find the value contained therein, in column E.

Comment: Thanks! iferror was a big help. That code didn't work for me, but i used nested iferror's and added 1 each time until it conformed to the list